# Get skewX and skewY from the box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, javascript-objects

In below fiddle I have tried to get the matrix from the square and now I want to help to get the skew x position and skew y position.

```js
var PosSkew = $(".rect1").css("transform") ||
  $(".rect1").css("-webkit-transform") ||
  $(".rect1").css("-moz-transform") ||
  $(".rect1").css("-ms-transform") ||
  $(".rect1").css("-o-transform")
alert(PosSkew);
```

```css
img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
.rect1 {
  margin: 25px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  -moz-transform: skew(20deg, 10deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(20deg, 10deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(20deg, 10deg);
  -o-transform: skew(20deg, 10deg) position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://cdn4.successories.com/480699-star-performance-acrylic-award.jpg" width="500">
<div class="rect1"></div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6CDFr/287/)

Comment: Please help me its urgent needs code for the SkewX and SkewY positions

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6CDFr/288/

Comment: I wants in degree like i have set transform:skew(20deg,10deg) that i want from the code

Comment: Please check the another example i have tried get success for Rotation of the box but not getting how to achieve skew positions https://jsfiddle.net/6CDFr/290/

Comment: Please post your code here; don't spread it around in fiddles: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6CDFr/291/

Comment: @AshishBhatt - above, plz check

Comment: Yes works but with some random way like if we put transform:skew(-50deg,10deg); its not working also needs to know how can i fetch if we have skew and rotate both for eg. transform:skew(-50deg,10deg) rotate(57deg);